# How to display my select/option in Angular 14?

Tags: angular, select

I can't display my select and i dont understand why. I can see it in the [inspector][1] but its not display...

First I was trying to get data from my service and it was not working, then i tried in static in the form component and it was not working to...
here in the my component and the template:

```js
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Route, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Spot} from '../spot';
import { SpotService } from '../spot.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-spot-form',
  templateUrl: './spot-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./spot-form.component.css']
})
export class SpotFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() spot: Spot;
  types: string[]= ["fdezfez", "rzefezfze", "zefdzef"]
  departements: string[] = ["fdezfez", "rzefezfze", "zefdzef"]
  isAddform: boolean;



  constructor(private spotService: SpotService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.types = this.spotService.getSpotTypeList();
    // this.departements = this.spotService.getDepList();
    this.isAddform = this.router.url.includes('add');
  
  }

  hasType(type: string): boolean {
    return this.spot.type.includes(type);

  }
```

```html
<form *ngIf="spot" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #spotForm="ngForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s8 offset-s2">
      <div class="card-panel">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Nom</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9àéèç ]{1,25}$"
            [(ngModel)]="spot.nom" name="name" #name="ngModel">

          <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="card-panel red accent-1">
            Le nom du Spot est requis (1-25).
          </div>

        </div>

        <div *ngIf="isAddform" class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Image</label>
          <input type="url" class="form-control" id="picture" required [(ngModel)]="spot.picture"         name="picture"
            #picture="ngModel">

          <div [hidden]="picture.valid || picture.pristine" class="card-panel red accent-1">
            L'image du spot est requise.
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="type">Type</label>
          <select #type="ngModel" name='type' class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="spot.type">
            <option *ngFor="let type of types" [value]="type">{{type}}</option>
          </select>
        </div>


        <!-- <div class="form-group">
            <select  name="departement" ngModel>
              <option  *ngFor="let departement of departements" value="departement" >{{departement}}</option>
            </select>
            <label for="departement">Département</label>
    
        </div> -->


        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="localisation">localisation</label>
          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="localisation" required
            pattern="^-?([1-8]?[1-9]|[1-9]0)\\.{1}\\d{1,6}" [(ngModel)]="spot.localisation" name="localisation"
            #localisation="ngModel">
          <div [hidden]="localisation.valid || localisation.pristine" class="card-panel red accent-1">
            [latitude,longitude]
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="divider"></div>
        <div class="section center">
          <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn" [disabled]="!spotForm.form.valid">
            Valider</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<h3 *ngIf="!spot" class="center">
  <app-loader></app-loader>
</h3>
```

Thanks you for your help !
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ3mW.png

Answer (score 1):

Well you are making your `<select>` select an option with a property of a bound model (`spot.type`) and you are generating the options available using the `types` property of your component. Are you sure the value of `spot.type` you're giving is always available within the `types` array?

If it is not, I am pretty sure no options will be set as selected in the browser, which means an empty `<select>`, which may simply mean it will not be displayed by your browser.

Also, using `[value]` on an option will only handle strings. Maybe use `[ngValue]` instead.